# Event bridge api destination with OAuth connection not working

Tags: c#, oauth, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to create event bridge api destination with OAuth authorization.

```
var oAuthAuthorizationProps = new OAuthAuthorizationProps
{
    AuthorizationEndpoint = "authorizationEndpoint",
    ClientId = "clientId",
    ClientSecret =  SecretValue.UnsafePlainText("testSecret"),
    HttpMethod = HttpMethod.POST,
};
```

And I'm using these authorization props to create connection:

```
Connection connection = new Connection(this, "TestConnectionName", new ConnectionProps
{
    Description = "Test Connection",
    ConnectionName = "TestConnectionName",    
    Authorization = Authorization.Oauth(oAuthAuthorizationProps)
});
```

This code is throwing an error when creating the connection with OAuth authorisation:

> Error occurred during operation 'AWS::Events::Connection'.
> (HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)

But if I change the authorisation to API key, then this is working perfectly fine. Will be really grateful for any help.

Comment: Can you run in debug mode and paste a full stack trace into your question please?